# Compute annual mean using x-arrays

Tags: time-series, python-xarray

I have a `python xarray` dataset with `time,x,y` for its dimensions and `value1` as its variable.  I'm trying to compute annual mean of `value1` for each `x,y` coordinate pair.

I've run into this function while reading the docs:

```
ds.groupby('time.year').mean()
```

This seems to compute a single annual mean for **all** `x,y` coordinate pairs in `value1` at each given time slice
rather than the annual means of **individual** `x,y` coordinate pairs at each given time slice.

While the code snippet above produces the wrong output,  I'm very interested in its oversimplified form.  I would really like to figure out the "X-arrays trick" to doing annual mean for a given `x,y` coordinate pair rather than hacking it together myself.

Cam someone point me in the right direction? Should I temporarily turn this into a `pandas` object?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To avoid the default of averaging over all dimensions, you simply need to supply the dimension you want to average over explicitly:
`ds.groupby('time.year').mean('time')`

Comment: Thank you! It works! Can you give me tips on how I should be reading X-array documentation? Is this something ubiquitous and something that someone using pandas would be able to do as well? (my background is 0 knowledge of Pandas, trying to learn X-arrays)

Comment: I would suggest reading the narrative sections that you are interested in (e.g., http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/groupby.html#apply in this case). This feature is pretty different from pandas, so it just be something that we did a poor job of explaining.

Answer (score 1):

Note, that calling `ds.groupby('time.year').mean('time')` **will be incorrect** if you are working with monthly and not daily data. Taking the mean will place equal weight on months of different length, e.g., Feb and July, which is wrong.

Instead use below from [NCAR](https://ncar.github.io/esds/posts/2021/yearly-averages-xarray/):

```
def weighted_temporal_mean(ds, var):
  """
  weight by days in each month
  """
  # Determine the month length
  month_length = ds.time.dt.days_in_month

  # Calculate the weights
  wgts = month_length.groupby("time.year") / month_length.groupby("time.year").sum()

  # Make sure the weights in each year add up to 1
  np.testing.assert_allclose(wgts.groupby("time.year").sum(xr.ALL_DIMS), 1.0)

  # Subset our dataset for our variable
  obs = ds[var]

  # Setup our masking for nan values
  cond = obs.isnull()
  ones = xr.where(cond, 0.0, 1.0)

  # Calculate the numerator
  obs_sum = (obs * wgts).resample(time="AS").sum(dim="time")

  # Calculate the denominator
  ones_out = (ones * wgts).resample(time="AS").sum(dim="time")

  # Return the weighted average
  return obs_sum / ones_out

average_weighted_temp = weighted_temporal_mean(ds_first_five_years, 'TEMP')
```